# Login as root to shell using ruby script

Tags: ruby, shell, vagrant

I want to login as root and run the remaining script

for that i used

**system 'sudo su'** but it fails.Here is the ruby script.

My requirement is to login as root on the system  by prompting for password  and then become the root user and run the remaining script.Please help me i am new to ruby

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :
server_disk='server.vdi'
desktop_disk='desktop.vdi'
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
 config.vm.box = "centos/7"
 config.vm.define "classroom" do |s|
  s.vbguest.auto_update = false
  s.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.254"
  s.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  #s.vm.synced_folder "../repos", "/repos", owner: "root", group: "root"
  s.vm.synced_folder "scripts/classroom", "/usr/local/scripts", type: "rsync", owner: "root", group: "root"
  s.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
   chmod u+x /usr/local/scripts/classroom.sh
   /usr/local/scripts/classroom.sh
  SHELL
 end
 system 'sudo su'
 config.vm.define "server" do |a|
  a.vbguest.auto_update = false
  a.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
   unless File.exist?(server_disk)
    v.customize ['createhd', '--filename', server_disk, '--size', 20 * 1024]
   end
   v.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'IDE Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', server_disk]
   end
  a.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.11"
  a.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  a.vm.synced_folder "scripts/server", "/usr/local/scripts", type: "rsync", owner: "root", group: "root"
  a.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
   chmod u+x /usr/local/scripts/server.sh
   /usr/local/scripts/server.sh
  SHELL
  end 
 config.vm.define "desktop" do |b|
  b.vbguest.auto_update = false
  b.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
   unless File.exist?(desktop_disk)
    v.customize ['createhd', '--filename', desktop_disk, '--size', 20 * 1024]
   end
   v.customize ['storageattach', :id, '--storagectl', 'IDE Controller', '--port', 1, '--device', 0, '--type', 'hdd', '--medium', desktop_disk]
   end
  b.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  b.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", disabled: true
  b.vm.synced_folder "scripts/desktop", "/usr/local/scripts", type: "rsync", owner: "root", group: "root"
  b.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
   chmod u+x /usr/local/scripts/desktop.sh
   /usr/local/scripts/desktop.sh
  SHELL
  end
end
```

Comment: How it's fails? Do you know what the command `sudo su` does? `sudo` execute command as another user, `su` run a command with substitute user and group.

Comment: so it should be sudo su root

Comment: then it should work right

Comment: but i am getting error as /home/midhun/lab/virtualbox/Vagrantfile:18: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt in PATH, mode 040777